# OSGi - How to get a new bundle to run via an existing bndrun file

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle, bnd, bndtools

I am new to the Java OSGi framework and have inherited a project which needs new functionality. The project has multiple bundles and is set up to run on Eclipse with all the required plugins etc.

There is a *start.bndrun* file which when run via the "Run OSGi" option on Eclipse, starts off the main application and runs all the bundles via the their `activate()` functions.

The problem is, when I create my own simple component and bundle as below, ExampleProviderImpl, export the required packages etc. and try to add it to the "Run Bundles" option of *start.bndrun*, it just doesn't seem to run.

```
package Test;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Activate;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;

@Component
public class ExampleProviderImpl
{

   @Activate
   void activate()
   {
      System.out.println("HELLO FROM ExampleProviderImpl.class");
      System.out.println("HELLO FROM ExampleProviderImpl.class");
      System.out.println("HELLO FROM ExampleProviderImpl.class");
      System.out.println("HELLO FROM ExampleProviderImpl.class");
      System.out.println("HELLO FROM ExampleProviderImpl.class");
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you check if your class is actually ending up inside the bundle jar? Another thing to check for is. Do you have the scr (declarative services extender) bundle running?

Comment: Are you running on Felix or Equinox?
Inside Equinox you have to add the header "Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy" to the bnd file. Otherwise DS/SCR will not automatically start your bundle and the service.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by

> it just doesn't seem to run.

you mean that nothing gets printed out. If so that is most likely because components are by default lazy and will not be activated until they are needed. Try adding `immediate = true` to your annotation to force component activation:

```java
@Component(immediate = true)
public class ExampleProviderImpl
```

**UPDATE**

The above assumes the bundle was properly added, resolved and started in the runtime. To check if that is indeed the case

- Make sure the bundle was properly added to `Run Requirements`
- Make sure that `auto-resolve on save` is checked or click `Resolve` button [image]
- Make sure resolution does not result in errors and your bundle is added the `Run Bundles` section.
- After staring the environment / deploying the bundle, go to Gogo shell and issue `lb` command. Make sure your bundle is `Active`

If something goes wrong on during any of those steps please update the question with all relevant information.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However it still doesn't work in my case (Nothing is printed). What would be the correct way to add a new bundle / component to a bndrun file? I put the new components in both the "Run requirements" and "Run bundles" sections

Comment: Can you update your question with the content of the `start.bndrun` file? Normally you only need to add the bundle into the `Run requirements` and then resolve. The resolver should update the `Run bundles` sections.

Comment: @MilenThanks again for your help. I have added my new bundle to the "Run Requirements" section as you explain. "Auto-resolve on save" is checked. When I select Resolve, my bundle shows up there , and also in "Run Bundles", so it looks like it is going to work. However, I still don't get anything printed out. When I check the Felix console, my bundle doesn't show up whatsoever, like non-existent. I have added "(immediate = true)" also to the Component

Comment: There is also a bnd.bnd file along with the bndrun file in that main project. Should the bundle be added to the "Run Requirements" section of that bnd.bnd file also? When I do this, it doesn't resolve, with errors such as "Capabilities satisfying the following requirements could not be found:"

Comment: No. Normally you don't have "Run Requirements" in `bnd.bnd` files. Those are for configuring the bundle not the runtime. How do you start your runtime?

Comment: Inside the bndrun file , there is a "Run Osgi" option at the top-right. I am using Eclipse IDE with all the required plugins. All other bundles part of the repository get activated and run fine, as I can see via the Felix Console along with debug messages on the console. Even If I add new packages and services to already existing bundles, they activate and work fine. However, not one new/separate bundle that I have created by myself yet gets activated. I've been trying well over a week now.

Comment: So you add it to the `bndrun` file, save, it's resolved without errors,  you can see it in "Run Bundles", you run it from bndtools UI and it's still not in the runtime? That's weird. I'm afraid there are no more "typical" issues  I can think of. Perhaps if you can share the `bndrun` file it may throw some more light on the issue.

Comment: What's the best way to share it?

Comment: Edit your question and add it there.